# Lendo PDF com DefaultStreamedContent. Como fechá-lo?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, stream

Tenho uma página JSF onde eu gero um PDF e preciso mostrá-lo na tela.

Para isso, criei um `<p:media>`

Está funcionando, porém o arquivo PDF fica preso (nunca é fechado) e com o tempo isso acaba derrubando o Tomcat por `Many files open`.

Já tentei fechar o `FileInputStream` no final do método `getStream()`, mas isso causa erro -> `Error in streaming dynamic resource. Stream Close`

Alguém tem alguma sugestão?

xhtml:

```
<p:dialog>
   <p:media value="#{reportMB.stream}" player="pdf" cache="disable"/>
</p:dialog>
```

ManagedBean (@SessionScope):

```
public StreamedContent getStream(){
    StreamedContent content=null;
    FileInputStream fis=null;
    try{
        File pdf = new File("/meudiretorio/meuarquivo.pdf");
        fis = new FileInputStream(pdf);
        content=new DefaultStreamedContent(fis,"application/pdf","nomequalquer");
    }catch(IOException e){
    }
    return content;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que encontrei [nesta questão do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18400078/1683070) e vejo na implementação da classe [`DefaultStreamedContent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.1/org/primefaces/model/DefaultStreamedContent.java#DefaultStreamedContent), o Stream nunca é fechado através do método `close`.

Você também não pode fechá-lo dentro do método pois o mesmo ainda será lido e transmitido ao usuário.

A [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18465113/1683070) apontada pelo mesmo autor da questão citada acima foi copiar os bytes do arquivo para um *stream* em memória, pois dessa forma o `StreamedContent` não fica vinculado ao arquivo no disco. O problema dessa abordagem é que o arquivo será lido todo em memória.

Outra opção, que não teria problemas relacionados à memória, porém me parece uma gambiarra, seria salvar uma referência ao `FileInputStream` original como um atributo da requisição ou da sessão (dependendo de quantas requisições o PrimeFaces faz para recuperar o PDF) e então implementar um *listener* para executar o `close` ao final da requisição, onde o PrimeFaces já teria enviado os dados para o usuário.

Uma terceira alternativa seria criar um novo `InputStream` como um *wrapper* para o `FileInputStream` de forma que detectasse o final do arquivo e então incovasse o `close` no stream do arquivo automaticamente.

Comment: Acabei de testar uma abordagem semelhante à solução do autor  new ByteArrayInputStream(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(pdf)) mas tmb acho que terei problema com memória. Vou tentar implementar um wrapper como vc sugeriu. Vamos ver no que dá ;)

Answer (score 0):

`StreamedContent.getStream` é fechado pelas classes:

- `FileDownloadActionListener`
- `PrimeResourceHandler`

Então ao final da requisição o próprio Primefaces se encarrega de fechar o `InputStream`.